# How do I confirm the output from the sklearn transform model (sc.transform)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, transform, sklearn-pandas

I am learning about the StandardScaler module in sklearn.  I understand the sc.fit obtains the mean of the data and uses it to transform the train and the test of the data, but I do not understand what mathematical function is being performed on the data array with the sc.mean_ obtained from sc.fit.

How do I confirm that the output I receive from sc.transform or sc.fit_transform is what I want, or if it is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
df.describe()
```

to see your desired transformation.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
# 4 samples/observations and 2 variables/features
data = np.array([[0, 0], [1, 0], [0, 1], [1, 1]])
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['V1', 'V2']).astype('float64')
columns_scaling = ['V1', 'V2']
scaler = StandardScaler()
df[columns_scaling]= scaler.fit_transform(df[columns_scaling])
df.describe().apply(lambda s: s.apply(lambda x: format(x, 'g')))
```